# Incrementing a variable onclick

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to build a vanilla js carousel. I want to incrementally increase or decrease a variable onClick, but I'm getting an Undefined issue. If I embed the the code in the HTML file everything works fine, when I move it to an external js file, I get an Undefined error. I feel like I'm missing some sort of information about scope.

```js
let i = 0;

function carouselControl() {
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel">
    <a onclick="carouselControl(i--);">
      <div class="carousel__control"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/Caret_left_font_awesome.svg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1125/750"></div>
    <div class="carousel__img hidden"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1126/750"></div>
    <div class="carousel__img hidden"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1127/750"></div>
    <a onclick="carouselControl(i++);">
      <div class="carousel__control"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Caret_right_font_awesome.svg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you made sure that you included the external js file also if you move it to as external?

Comment: @kevin did you include the javascript file using script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `carouselControl` function is not expecting any parameters (the parenthesis part).

When you call your function in the HTML `onclick`, you are passing the actual code in the parameters part.

Change your function to something like:

```
function carouselControl(operation){
    if (operation == "increase") i++;
    if (operation == "decrease") i--;
}
```

And in your HTML do:

`<a onclick="carouselControl("decrease");"><div class="carousel__control"><img src="../img/symbols/left.svg"></a></div>`

`<a onclick="carouselControl("increase");"><div class="carousel__control"><img src="../img/symbols/right.svg"></a></div>`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to up vote but I don't count in the eyes of stack overflow yet.

Comment: That's OK, thank you for the upvote. If this solved your issue, you can accept the answer by clicking on the little checkmark item :)
Good luck with your coding!

Comment: I think it's the answer, but I keep getting NaN when trying to access the i variable inside the function. It was defined globally as 0 but even if I pass it into the function it give me a NaN. I've tried wrapping it in parseInt() and Number(). I have to be missing something about scope.

Comment: Hmmm...is the javascript code inside the HTML code? Or is it being imported?

Comment: It’s being imported via an app.js file. I’ve defined it in the global scope ( let i = 0; )

Comment: Maybe try to move the javascript code inside the HTML to test? This example here is working fine: https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/MRQMEa (check the console on the bottom)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a variable that is unknown in the first file, also you did not define that the `carouselControl()` will receive any variables with the function call. What you can do is :

```js
let i = 0;

function carouselControl(condition) {
  if(condition == 1) // increasing the "i" value
    i++;
  else if ( condition == 0) // decreasing the "i" value
    i--;
  console.log(i);
}
```

and at the first file you would just have to change the  `carouselControl(i--)` to `carouselControl(1)` for the button that you want to increase the number and `carouselControl(0)` for the button that you want to decrease the number.